How to pass password in Powershell or Powershell ISE script
DISCLAIMER: I don't know squat about scripting.
I need to access our Cyerbark vault via API. Our Cyerbark group gave me a Powershell ISE script to run. The script calls an SSL cert that requires a password. The cert is owned by a a different IT group that doesn't know Pshell, so I'm having trouble getting them to work together and give me a script that works by sending the password as well. I was hoping I could get some help on how to do that.
Here is the script they gave me.
$certPath = "D:\Folder\SSLCertName.pfx" 
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certPath 
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://API_URL' -Certificate $cert

How do I get the password embedded in the script?
I've anonymized the folder path, cert name, and api URL., but the single and double quotes are part of the script.
Thanks for any help!
-Craig
I tried googling how to do this and did find the password parameter, but can't get it to work correctly.

Use -Password : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-pfxcertificate?view=powershell-7.4#-password

"How do I get the password embedded in the script?" - you don't, this is a catch22. See How to securely store a password for a script run every day using a Windows task scheduler? for an explanation and alternatives.
